# map reduce directly on Airflow

Tags: mapreduce, airflow

What is the downside for implementing map reduce directly on Airflow?

I can dynamically create operators for map and reduce when creating the DAG for Airflow.

Answer (score 3):

**Airflow >= 2.3.0:**

Support for map reduce like workflows was added by implementing AIP (Airflow Improvement Proposal) to support it. See [AIP-42 Dynamic Task Mapping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-42+Dynamic+Task+Mapping)
You can set [mapped tasks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) to achieve that.

**Airflow < 2.3.0:**

Airflow does not support map-reduce.
You can still create tasks & DAGs dynamically but not in a map-reduce manner see [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#dynamic-dag-generation).

Answer (score 0):

Airflow now supports dynamic task mapping in its v2.3.0 release.

See release announcement for more info [Apache Airflow 2.3.0 is here](https://airflow.apache.org/blog/airflow-2.3.0/)